# HP elitebook (HP X360 1040 G10) screen flickering (LTS 22.04)

Tags: hp, screen, flicker

I see similar posts, and tried every solution, but no luck - can anyone help me what I might try to fix this? This is VERY disappointing to say the least.

Further information as requested:

```
$ lspci -knn | grep -iEA5 'vga|3d|display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a7a1] (rev 04)
    DeviceName: Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8b41]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a71d] (rev 01)
--
00:06.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a73d] (rev 01)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:07.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a76e] (rev 01)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:07.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a72f] (rev 01)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
```

---

```
$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: Intel
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) Graphics (RPL-P)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Comment: Attach output of `lspci -knn | grep -iEA5 'vga|3d|display'` and `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` terminal commands

Comment: You could try Ubuntu 23.10 which has a newer graphical stack